# android Gps code toast

Tags: android, android-context, android-toast

I made a simple app to make a toast of the latitude. I ran the code on my nexus 5 and it works but when I run it on the Samsung galaxy s4 it does not show a toast. Why?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


     String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
              500,  
              1, this);         
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    log =   Double.toString(location.getLongitude());   

    lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());  

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Add your logcat/errortrace. What exactly dont work? Maybe GPS is turned off on your Samsung s4 device.

Comment: @Xry-there is no errors and the gps is turned on

Comment: @Xry- no, Nexus is on 5.0 and the s4 is on 4.4.2

Comment: Hi sara, try using this instead of getBaseContext()

Comment: Do you know for sure if `onLocationChanged()` is being called at all on the Samsung S4? If not, add logging (not Toast) and check Logcat.

Comment: please change question title as this is quite useless

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works with getApplicationContext() (member of the Activity
class).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()

HTH
--Gerhard